# RewriteRule causes a malfunction of the other path (subdir), css/imgs/js

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, relative-path, absolute-path

Like title, that rule:

```
RewriteRule pagtwo/pic/(.*) index.php?pic=$1 [PT,QSA]
```

Rule working, but not the file included by subdirectory for example

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" media="all">
<img src="imgs/image.jpg">
```

and goes on

Directories are css, imgs and js, why they do not included correctly? Must I insert the absolute path for that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to you page header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Because you're using relative paths, what would normally resolve relatively from `/` won't woek when resolving relative from `/pagtwo/pic/`.